# c++ - How to interpret symbols in 'duplicated symbols' error?

Tags: c++, linker

I'm working on a c++ program.

As several files are dependent on each other, I implemented them all in once and then I got compiling errors.

Here are those error messages:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN5RendrlsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_8Vector3DE in:
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/ray_tracer.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN5RendrlsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS_8Vector2DE in:
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/ray_tracer.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN5RendrlsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_8Vector3DE in:
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/CGL/svgparser.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN5RendrlsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS_8Vector2DE in:
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/CGL/svgparser.cpp.o
...
duplicate symbol __ZN5RendrlsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS_8Vector2DE in:
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/src/CGL/triangulation.cpp.o
ld: 15 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [Rendr] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Rendr.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Rendr] Error 2
```

I'm not pasting my whole bunch of code because my problem is I can't understand things like `__ZN5RendrlsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS_8Vector2DE`, therefore I don't know how to locate the incorrect pieces of code.

I've only run into symbols like `_main` before and they are pretty easy to understand.

I have defined `Vector3D` and `Vector2D` classes, but how to interpret the exact symbols in the error messages? I think they represent some functions or variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are "decorated" or "mangled" names. Different C++ compilers have different rules for name decoration.

You can demangle them by using this handy online tool: https://demangler.com/

For example:

```
__ZN5RendrlsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS_8Vector2DE
```

is demangled to

```
_Rendr::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Rendr::Vector2D const&)
```

If you've got `c++filt` available, you can do this at the command line:

```
$ c++filt -_ __ZN5RendrlsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS_8Vector2DE`
Rendr::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Rendr::Vector2D const&)
```